# Запуск go-micro

Tags: golang, google-protobuf

Пробую запустить тестовые примеры:

```
package main

import (
"fmt"

micro "github.com/micro/go-micro"
proto "github.com/micro/go-micro/examples/service/proto"
"golang.org/x/net/context"
)

type Greeter struct{}

func (g *Greeter) Hello(ctx context.Context, req *proto.HelloRequest, rsp *proto.HelloResponse) error {
rsp.Greeting = "Hello " + req.Name
return nil
}

func main() {
// Create a new service. Optionally include some options here.
service := micro.NewService(
    micro.Name("greeter"),
    micro.Version("latest"),
    micro.Metadata(map[string]string{
        "type": "helloworld",
    }),
)

// Init will parse the command line flags. Any flags set will
// override the above settings. Options defined here will
// override anything set on the command line.
service.Init()

// Register handler
proto.RegisterGreeterHandler(service.Server(), new(Greeter))

// Run the server
if err := service.Run(); err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
}
```

У меня выдается следующая ошибка:

Starting Process MicroServer.exe  ...
2016/09/21 11:09:48 Listening on [::]:64497
2016/09/21 11:09:48 Broker Listening on [::]:64498
2016/09/21 11:09:48 Registering node: greeter-0026467f-7fc2-11e6-b412-6cf049da6b
9d
Put http://127.0.0.1:8500/v1/agent/service/register: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8500: co
nnectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused
 it.

End Process exit status 0

Press enter key to continue

Пробую запускать под win7, еще при запуске требует разрешить сетевой доступ по пути: C:\users\nikita\appdata\local\temp\go-build139080506\command-line-arguments_obj\exe;

Но такого каталога у меня нет, я что то не установил??

Заранее благодарю!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже что вы запускаете программу через go run - при этом программа компилируется во временный файл, путь к которому у вас и показан.

Вариант решения например такой: Компилировать программу вручную через go build и потом отдельно запускать бинарник. Тогда у вас путь будет постоянным и вы сможете добавить его в разрешения 1 раз и запомнить его. Можно делать go build -o app.exe & app.exe - тогда компилирование и запуск будут делаться одной командой.

А ошибка выдается как раз потому что Firewall запрещает подключения.